# Comparing two text cells to get four outputs

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'm building up a checking sheet for my work for issuing of commemorative coins. In 'Column F' I have a if formula running that answers 'Yes' or 'No' to indicate if the employee is eligible to have a coin issued. 'Column G' is a manual input of 'Yes' or 'No' to indicate if the employee has actually been issued a coin.

What I'm after is a formula to put into 'Column H' to give the following outputs (so I can run a 4 icon traffic light condition formatting, I know the formula and formatting for this once I can get the four outputs), however I'm unsure of how to do it and I've been playing around with formulas for a few hours.

```
 G     F     H
Yes   Yes    1 
Yes   No     2
No    Yes    3
No    No     4
```

Hope I explained this with enough sense to get an answer. Please note I'm working in Excel 2007, as that's what work has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(F1="Yes", IF(G1="Yes", 1, 2), IF(G1="Yes",3,4))
```

Note this doesn't explicitly check the contents of a cell that isn't yes, it just assumes Yes and No are the only options. If you want an explicit check for No (and then a different result if a cell is neither Yes nor No) then it's a bit more complicated.

(Also, I'm assuming you meant F,G,H in that order rather than G,F,H as you wrote!)

Comment: Thanks Vicky, works exactly as I wanted it to. Yes I did confuse my alphabet.